# Datatable colspan

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

My table header is look like the following.I am using datatable pdf export to download it as pdf.The problem is it not showing the first tr in the pdf because of the colspan. Is there is any way to display this?How can I add colspan for td in the first row of thead of pdf?

Thanks

```
<thead>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="5" ></td>
            <td colspan="5" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th ></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></td>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
 </thead>
```

Comment: Please reproduce your problem in a code snippet or jsfiddle and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table,tr,th,td{
border:1px solid;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;"> 
<thead>
            <tr height="25">
                <td colspan="5" >td</td>
                <td colspan="5" >td</td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="25">
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            <th width="10%">th</th>
            </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Try It Once